# Using explorer.exe to get a folder name and path as input in a java program

Tags: java, explorer

I'm trying to develop a java project metrics calculator.

In order to explore the source code, the user has to give the complete source location as an absolute path such as "C:\Users\User\Desktop\src"

Another way is to open explorer.exe program from cmd and from there explore the folder name and select it.

Example : While we try to extract using Winzip we click on "extract to" option which invokes an "explorer.exe" or similar application allowing user to select the folder

How can I implement this feature in my java project.

Please feel free to suggest any viable solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just FYI I tried googling for the last 2 hours. May be I couldn't search with the correct explicit keywords or description. But it's rather unpleasant to blame someone for not trying enough and being lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through your question I take it you'd like to choose the file rather than explicitly giving the absolute path, You can use JFileChooser ( links below ) and try implementing them in your code

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html
>
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-swing-jfilechooser/